# Google Review on my Website

Tags: google-places-api, review

I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to feed google reviews into my website? I would like it to be kinda of a testimonial type page. Or if i could feed it with a slider reviews that would be really awesome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I recently needed to get reviews as well for a similar application, so I created a jQuery plugin that will fetch ALL the reviews and allows for options to be passed in for filtering.

[google-places jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/peledies/google-places)

This question is kind of old but maybe it will help someone else

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) now supports the return of up to five reviews from a [Place Details Request](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceDetailsRequests).

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRYAAAAciqGsTRX1mXRvuXSH2ErwW-jCINE1aLiwP64MCWDN5vkXvXoQGPKldMfmdGyqWSpm7BEYCgDm-iv7Kc2PF7QA7brMAwBbAcqMr5i1f4PwTpaovIZjysCEZTry8Ez30wpEhCNCXpynextCld2EBsDkRKsGhSLayuRyFsex6JA6NPh9dyupoTH3g&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```